# [myclass encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error while using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, restkit, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to fill a dictionary with values from restkit. I save the dictionary using NSUserDefaults in my restEngine.m

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [mappingResult dictionary];

                   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict] forKey:kPopulateTableView ];
                   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When I build the app, it breaks with the error message:

"[myclass encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

it seems that in your NSDictionary `dict` you save objects that are not encodable. 
**BUT**
 
Only encodable objects can be used with an archiver.

To be encodable they must implement the `NSCoding protocol`

SO: myclass needs to implement NSCoding

---

For further info read the "Archives and Serializations Programming Guide"

Comment: So where should I implement my class using NSCoding? In my rest engine or where the class is actually defined? Sorry Im not familiar with NSCoding

Comment: in your class.. it is a protocol that defines 2? methods that you HAVE to provide then